# Dynamically store numeric values with absolute minimal bits?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am making a game with C#/Unity and want to minimise bandwidth usage.  Ten times a second the server updates clients with changes to unit positions.  The server only sends data if it has changed, and only sends the difference between this and last logged values; which may be positive or negative.  There may be anywhere from zero to a few thousand units in play at any one moment.

Default data for each unit is one ushort and four float variables (id, x, y, z, direction).  This would be 18 bytes + object (serialization) and datagram bytes.  Right now I'm sending that, but it's simply too much to have a thousand units running about... 18 * 10 * 1000 = 180kb/s.

This can be simplified to whole numbers, as I only care about say two decimal points of precision.  For example: 13.35 - 13.10 = 0.25 ... which we can store as 25.  If a lot of values are going to be much smaller than 255 (a byte) then the best solution will allow us to dynamically store only the bits required plus as little overhead as possible.  The solution will also allow us to send values which are much greater if need be.

This is useful for other server commands, like applying damage to units, which would require an id and damage value.  The damage value is probably going to be less than 20 most of the time.

Using C# how can I dynamically store the required data in as few bits as possible for network transport?

Comment: "datagram" sounds like UDP. UDP is not reliable. Do you think sending deltas, only is a good idea? Or do you sync regularly? Before going into bit-optimizations: are you _100% sure_ lags are caused by bandwidth / network throughput?

Comment: @Fildor Good point, but in this case Unity's network config can be set to reliable (I have for now), and there's other ways of approaching the issue.  The problem however is, if we have 1,000 unit corrections at 18 bytes each, ten times a second, that's 180kb/s.  Which is unacceptable.  Even if we use L4Z compression on top that's only going to about halve it.

Comment: You should add the appropriate unity-tags to get better answers more quickly.

Comment: You problem doesn't have any thing to due with transfer size.  The issue is really how organize the database of the game to allow updating values.  Once you design the update process the transfer process will be simple.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand, can you link any reading material to explain that please?

Comment: 18 bytes is not a lot of data.  Packing and unpacking would take more time.  The speed must include any packing and unpacking along with the math.  There is a lot of time required to convert a string number to a floating point number.  C# is not efficient of casting numbers from one type to another.  A simple solution is to multiple then floating point numbers by 100 and to the I/O as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

edit: added support for negative values.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```cs
public static UInt32 Pack(float dx, float dy, float dz)
{
    // Track if the incoming values are negative or not.
    // If they are, make them positive.
    bool ndx = false;
    bool ndy = false;
    bool ndz = false;

    if (dx < 0)
    {
        dx *= -1;
        ndx = true;
    }

    if (dy < 0)
    {
        dy *= -1;
        ndy = true;
    }

    if (dz < 0)
    {
        dz *= -1;
        ndz = true;
    }

    // breakdown:
    //
    // (dx * 100)
    // Take a decimal value and scale it to an integer value. So 0.25 becomes 25.
    //
    // (int)(dx * 100)
    // Truncate to an integer.
    //
    // ((int)(dx * 100) % 100)
    // If this was something like 4.25 it would have been 425. This takes only
    // the last two digits (mod 100).
    // This will go into the lowest 8 bits.
    // 
    // ((int)(dy * 100) % 100) << 8
    // Do the same, but stuff it into bits 8-15.
    //
    // ((int)(dz * 100) % 100) << 16
    // Do the same, but stuff it into bits 16-23.
    var packed = (UInt32)(((int)(dx * 100) % 100) | ((int)(dy * 100) % 100) << 8 | ((int)(dz * 100) % 100) << 16);

    // Since 100 is less than 128, doing "% 100" will result in a seven bit number.
    // If the incoming value was negative, set the highest bit to flag that:
    if (ndx)
        packed |= (uint)0x80;
    if (ndy)
        packed |= (uint)0x8000;
    if (ndz)
        packed |= (uint)0x800000;

    return packed;
}

public static void Unpack(UInt32 input, out float dx, out float dy, out float dz)
{
    // breakdown:
    //
    // input & 0x7f
    // Take the first 7 bits.
    //
    // (float)(input & 0x7f)
    // Cast to a float value. So 25 becomes 25f.
    //
    // (float)(input & 0x7f) / 100
    // Shift back down to a deci number. So 25 -> 0.25.
    //
    // (float)((input & 0x7f00) >> 8) / 100;
    // Do the same thing, but with bits 8-14.
    //
    // (float)((input & 0x7f0000) >> 16) / 100;
    // Do the same thing, but with bits 15-23.
    dx = (float)(input & 0x7f) / 100;
    dy = (float)((input & 0x7f00) >> 8) / 100;
    dz = (float)((input & 0x7f0000) >> 16) / 100;

    // If the negative flag is set, make this a negative value:
    dx *= (input & (uint)0x80) > 1 ? -1f : 1f;
    dy *= (input & (uint)0x8000) > 1 ? -1f : 1f;
    dz *= (input & (uint)0x800000) > 1 ? -1f : 1f;
}
```

And as you can see here, this solution can produce rounding errors:

```
> var p = Pack(0.25f, -.67f, -0.12f);
> Unpack(p, out a, out b, out c);
> a
0.25
> b
-0.67
> c
-0.11
>
```

Comment: Comments may help explain the code. Can you please edit this to explain your use of the bitwise operator?  I'm unfamiliar with it, though it looks like you're forcing the numeric data of three values into just the one?

Answer (score 1):

(First up, I second the thought that this *might* be premature optimization.  Have you made absolutely certain there's no structural/architectural way around this problem?  Lessening update rates for distant objects?  etc?)

Anyways:

Please don't dismiss this idea out of hand immediately (due to CPU complexity) but you might want to consider digging in to how the ZIP and JPG formats work.

The reason I mention that is because how ZIP fundamentally works is by using "variable length" storage.  Instead of saying "each data chunk is one byte", it instead compresses things down by figuring out a good way of representing data.

Imagine I was storing a text file of:

```
Seeeeeeeeeee meeeeeeeeeee leeeeeeeeeeeeeeeean freeeeeeeeeeeeeely.
```

... a regular text file would take a byte per character, or 520 bits.  But... why?  Realistically, you would expect an average character in that file to be 'e' - what if you could simply use a single bit to represent the 'e' character?
  If the first bit is '0', it's an 'e'; otherwise, you have to read more bits to figure out what character it is.  Maybe something like:

```
0: 'e'
100: ' '
101: 'l'
11000: 'S'
11001: 'm'
11010: 'a'
11011: 'n'
11100: 'f'
11101: 'r'
11110: 'y'
11111: '.'
```

How much space would the string take?  52 e's at one bit apiece, 3 spaces and 2 l's at 3 bits apiece, and 8 other chars at 5 bits apiece: 52x1+5x3+8x5 = 107 bits.  (There are *better* ways to compress that string, but I'm trying to keep it simple.)

How does this fit into your problem?

You're going to have a *lot* of values that are low - the closer you get to 0, the more likely you'll see it (you'll have a lot of deltas of 0-4, and far fewer of 100-104.)  Why use 8 bits to store most of the values, if you expect *most* values to be storable in 4 bits?

I'm not saying "call a zip library on your data" (though that might work - I've never tried that on small memory segments to see how time-intensive it is) - but if you dig into variable-length encoding, you might be able to figure out a good scheme to represent your data using this sort of approach.

EDIT:

... and after doing some additional googling from my end, you might want to take a look at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.